# hessiankit exception NSRangeException

Tags: ios, objective-c, hessian

my **Service**

```
@protocol Service <NSObject>
-(int)getPersonCount;
-(id<Person>)getPerson:(int)index;
@end
```

my **Protocol**

```
@protocol Person
@property(assign, nonatomic) int age;
@property(retain, nonatomic) NSString* name;
@end
```

proxy is made in this way

```
id<Service> proxy = [CWHessianConnection proxyWithURL:url protocol:@protocol(Service)];
    int count = [proxy getPersonCount];
    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
        id<Person> person = [proxy getPerson:index];
        NSLog(@"age: %d name: %@", person.age, person.name);
    }
```

the result is `[__NSCFData getBytes:range:]: range {3, 1}` exceeds data length 3

It's the sample code from HessianKit doc ,i dont know what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply accessing data outside range. Maximum range should be {2, 1} and you are trying to get to 3.

Comment: But i am not control Array directly by myself,it's the hessiankit itself.